# implement tree iterator with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm writing spring boot application. I have the HashTree structure, sorted by specific field. And I have a specific method that iterates through the tree, so if it finds a value (used as comparator) it returns it and does not check for other values.

With code it will look something like this:

```
class Storage {

    TreeSet<Book> tree = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getNumberOfPages));

    public Book getBookWithSmallestNumberOfPagesButGreaterThanSpecific(int number) {
       iterator = tree.iterator();      
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           Book book = iterator.next();
           if (book.getNumberOfPages() > number) {
               return book;
           }
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

Please don't jurge that code, it's just for example, real code is much more complicated.

**So I want to do the same thing using Spring JPA**, and store Books in database.

My plan is:

- create index on numberOfPages column in order to iterate it in asc order
- get a coursor to the first database record
- return current element or get next element in a cursor.

The thing is I dont know how to get a cursor, all JPA methods return all elements in a List<>.

Please challenge my solution. I don't know if I move in a right direction. I'm pretty new to JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html),

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, direction, property);
List<ENTITY> findByProjectId(String projectId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I choose the page size? Will it be optimal solution to use Pageable with size 1?

Comment: page is page number. size is number of records on the page. So making size 1 would not make any sense. More details https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html.
Hope it helps.